# In PowerShell, can Test-Path (or something else) be used to validate multiple files when declaring a string array parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a function that accepts a string array parameter of files and I would like to use Test-Path (or something else) to ensure that all the files in the string array parameter exists. I would like to do this in the parameter declaration if possible.

Is this possible?

Comment: `-Path` does accept an array of strings so you could do it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use ValidateScript

```
param(
[parameter()]
[ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ })]
[string[]]$paths
)
```

For more documentation on parameter validation visit [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

You can set the parameter to use a validation script like this:

```
Function DoStuff-WithFiles{
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline)]
    [ValidateScript({
        If(Test-Path $_){$true}else{Throw "Invalid path given: $_"}
        })]
    [String[]]$FilePath)
Process{
    "Valid path: $FilePath"
}
}
```

It is recommended to not justpass back $true/$false as the function doesn't give good error messages, use a Throw instead, as I did above. Then you can call it as a function, or pipe strings to it, and it will process the ones that pass validation, and throw the error in the Throw statement for the ones that don't pass. For example I will pass a valid path (C:\Temp) and an invalid path (C:\Nope) to the function and you can see the results:

```
@("c:\temp","C:\Nope")|DoStuff-WithFiles
Valid path: c:\temp
DoStuff-WithFiles : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FilePath'. Invalid path given: C:\Nope
At line:1 char:24
+ @("c:\temp","C:\Nope")|DoStuff-WithFiles
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (C:\Nope:String) [DoStuff-WithFiles], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,DoStuff-WithFiles
```

**Edit:** I partially retract the Throw comment. Evidently it does give descriptive errors when the validation fails now (*thank you Paul!*). I could have sworn it (at least used to) just gave an error stating that it failed the validation and left off what it was validating and what it was validating against. For more complex validation scripts I would still use Throw though because the user of the script may not know what `$_ -match '^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$'` means if the error throws that at them (validating IPv4 address).

Comment: the default output of ValidateScript will also include the item that failed so as long as you only change that the throw declaration seems kind of redundant to me

Comment: Does it now? I thought it only gave fairly useless failure messages. Maybe that's changed since I first learned about ValidateScript

Comment: on my machine (v4) it does

Comment: Sure enough, I just checked it myself. Good to know. Thanks Paul!

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, your answer helped me to understand more validatescript but the answer of Paul was more straighforward for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

As @Matt said. `Test-Path` already accepts pipeline input, so you really just have to send the array directly in:

```
@($path1, $path2) | Test-Path
```

Which then returns:

```
> @("C:\foo", "C:\Windows") | Test-Path
False
True
```

If you just want to know if ALL of them exist:

```
($pathArray | Test-Path) -notcontains $false
```

Which yields:

```
 False
```